# changing indentation of nodes on v-treeview

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I cant find anything online about this.  I want to reduce the indentation of the nodes in v-treeview, making the tree slimmer so it can display more nodes in less width.

The v-treeview doesnt seem to handle indentation with padding, so changing the padding hasnt helped.  It seems like the width of the div that has the content changes programatically. Anyon delt with this before?

Ive tried altering the padding and width with css rules, to no avail.